# Resetting Angular Page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, reset

I have a button on my angular page that I want to be able to reset the page. By reset I mean take the page back to the original state as if the user just accessed the page for the first time. I was thinking about going the copying route so I tried something like this:

```
$scope.orig = angular.copy($rootScope);
```

But that threw [this error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/cpws). I have several scope variables and many controller variables. I don't want to save them all individually. I thought it would just be easier to copy the page in it's original condition and then reset it by retrieving the original version. But that doesn't seem to be a workable solution. Any ideas how to solve this problem?

**Edit 1:**
I tried Ben Felda's solution but couldn't get it to work. Here's my controller code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);

var MyCtrl = function($route, $scope, $log, $http, $sce, $q, $filter) {
    this.$route = $route;
    this.$scope = $scope;
    this.$log = $log;
    this.$http = $http;
    this.$sce = $sce;
    this.$q = $q;
    this.$filter = $filter;

    this.ShouldAutoStart = false;
    this.viewA = true;
    this.viewB = false;
    this.topButtonClicked = false;
    this.showIDTable = false;
    this.topRequest;
};

MyCtrl.prototype.reset = function() {
    var _this = this;
    console.log("route reloaded");
    _this.$route.reload();
};

MyCtrl.prototype.getInfo = function() {
    var _this = this;
    _this.reset();
    //do other stuff
};

MyCtrl.$inject = ['$route','$scope', '$log', '$http', '$sce', '$q', '$filter'];
app.controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<form ng-submit="dp.getInfo(dp.id)" class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" ng-model="dp.id" class="form-control" required/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I included the `angular-route.js` file in the `index.html`. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: save what you need into an inner object inside `$rootScope` and copy that instead of copying the whole monster object `$rootScope.myObject = {}; $rootScope.myObject.name = 'whatever'; $scope.orig = angular.copy($rootScope.myObject);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what other variables you have in play beyond what you posted, but move all of your instantiation code into a separate method so that you're controller looks something like this:

```
var MyCtrl = function($route, $scope, $log, $http, $sce, $q, $filter) {

    var vm = this;
    vm.$route = $route;
    vm.$scope = $scope;
    vm.$log = $log;
    vm.$http = $http;
    vm.$sce = $sce;
    vm.$q = $q;
    vm.$filter = $filter;
    vm.activate = activate() ;

    activate()

   function activate() {
        vm.ShouldAutoStart = false;
        vm.viewA = true;
        vm.viewB = false;
        vm.topButtonClicked = false;
        vm.showIDTable = false;
        vm.topRequest;
    }
};
```

Then just call the activate method on your controller when you want to reset it.

Answer (score 5):

Try using `$route.reload()`

[Angular API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route)

> Causes $route service to reload the current route even if $location hasn't changed.
>
> As a result of that, ngView creates new scope and reinstantiates the
>   controller.

Comment: He's talking about `$rootScope`, not `$route`

Comment: @AlonEitan understood, reloading the route re-instantiates the controller and the scope.  Saves alot of copy headache.

Comment: @BenFelda I tried this solution and updated my post to show the code. I still couldn't get all the variables to reset. Any idea what's wrong?